# Diff module shows 'No visible changes' for 'Geolocation' and 'International phone' fields

Tags: 8

I have "No visible changes" message for 'Geolocation' and 'International phone' fields change and have only one option "Don't compare" in Diff field configuration page /admin/config/content/diff/fields.

Can you help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Diff module can only compare fields for which a @FieldDiffBuilder class is implemented for that field and that class offers options for comparing that field.
For example, for a comment field, the Diff module implements the [`CommentFieldBuilder`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/diff/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/diff/Field/CommentFieldBuilder.php#L21) class, for which the options are given by  [`CommentFieldBuilder::buildConfigurationForm()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/diff/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/diff/Field/CommentFieldBuilder.php#L66).

```php
$form['compare_key'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => $this->t('Compare comment status key'),
  '#default_value' => $this->configuration['compare_key'],
);
$form['compare_string'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => $this->t('Compare comment status string'),
  '#default_value' => $this->configuration['compare_string'],
);

return parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
```

There isn't any issue in the module. A module should change the @FieldDiffBuilder class associated with the *Geolocation* and *International phone* fields, to make the Diff module able to compare their values.